# HTML data request to mysql Webapp

Tags: javascript, android, html, mysql, servlets

i've got a webapp that needs to request data from my mysql database, now it works fine using this method (for each apps, android and iOs) :

i have a webview that contains an html page that requests datas to my php page on my server that links to my mysql database. e.g:

```
    <script>
        var tolink = "http://www.mysite.altervista.org/pathto/mypage.php?FBID=" + id +"&FBUSER=" + usr +"&FEMAIL=" + email;
        var total = tolink + " #container";
        $( "#container" ).load(total);
        </script>
```

i think that in this way when i reach a lot of users (1500) the app crashes or runs slowly.

is there a better way to do that as the app is programmed all in native? without obviusly do that all in native..

i read so much of the servlet, is there a way to get datas faster from my html page in webview directly from these servlet?